# How to copy UV unwrap for internal use in blender?

Tags: texturing, uv

I wonder if there an option to save UV unwrap to use it in Blender (not export).

The point is that I have imported a fbx model with unwrapped UVs to blender, and now I want to modify UVs from fbx, but I need also preserve old UVs. I want to mix several identical texture nodes with different UV Map nodes (mix texture with different scale) and couldn't find an option to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Select the mesh, go to vertices properties (green triangle), UV maps panel and click the plus button; this will create a new UV map as an editable copy of the original.

You can have up to 8 UV maps for each object.

In the shader editor use the Input menu to add an UV node and choose which UV map to use for each texture node. If nothing is plugged, the default is the map with the camera icon in the UV maps list (usually the first one).

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot! It should very simplimize my workflow!